# fullcalendar scheduler mysql resources json

Tags: mysql, json, resources, fullcalendar

I am trying to use mysql for the following json. But how can build the children Room D1 and D2 in mysql? 
Right now I have difficultied to build up the master/detail relation for id "d" and his children "d1" and "d2". Please advise how to do this with mysql.

```
[
{ "id": "a", "title": "Auditorium A" },
{ "id": "b", "title": "Auditorium B", "eventColor": "green" },
{ "id": "c", "title": "Auditorium C", "eventColor": "orange" },
{ "id": "d", "title": "Auditorium D", "children": [
    { "id": "d1", "title": "Room D1" },
    { "id": "d2", "title": "Room D2" }
] },
```

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use Parent Id refer to this link http://fullcalendar.io/docs/resource_data/Resource_Object/

```
Use Parent Id refer to this link http://fullcalendar.io/docs/resource_data/Resource_Object/
```

```js
resources: [
    {
        id: 'a',
        title: 'Room A'
    },
    {
        id: 'a1',
        parentId: 'a',
        title: 'Room A1'
    },
    {
        id: 'a2',
        parentId: 'a',
        title: 'Room A2'
    }
]
```